# How to change `app:popupTheme` based on app's overall theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

In an app with a configurable theme, how does one set `app:popupTheme` to match the overall theme?

I created an app with a navigation drawer using Android Studio's wizard. I then modified this code to add a checkbox for selecting between a dark theme and a light theme at runtime and calling `setTheme` on the activity. The full code can be found in [this github repo](https://github.com/xenomachina/ExampleDayNightNavDrawer/tree/427bea20169dac7bf3a0137eff909954257c013a).

In `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`, Android Studio generated the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

This style is used in `app/src/main/res/layout/app_bar_main.xml`, also generated by Android Studio:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

The `app:popupTheme` attribute determines the style used by the "⋮" menu. This looks right when using the light theme, but when I switch the app to a dark theme at runtime the menu has the wrong colors. I know I can change `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`'s parent, like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

to make it work in the dark theme, but then the menu looks wrong when the light theme is active.

What is the correct way to have the menu's coloring dynamically adapt to the app's overall theme, whether dark or light? Should `app:popupTheme` change dynamically? Should `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`'s parent change dynamically? Something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished through the use of a custom `attr`:

1. Create `app/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml` with a custom `attr`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
    <attr name="popupOverlayStyle" format="reference"/>
   </resources>
   ```
2. In `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`, create a dark equivalent to `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay.Dark" 
        parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
   ```
3. In each theme, add an item setting the custom attr to the appropriate popup style:

   ```
   <!-- in the light AppTheme -->
   <item name="popupOverlayStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>

   <!-- in the dark AppTheme -->
   <item name="popupOverlayStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay.Dark</item>
   ```
4. In `app/src/main/res/layout/app_bar_main.xml` set `app:popupTheme` to reference the custom `attr`:

   ```
   app:popupTheme="?popupOverlayStyle"
   ```

Changing the app's theme will then automatically adjust which style `app:popupTheme` references.